# ¿Como abrir un archivo de un formato específico en otra App desde tu App en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, archivo

Estoy trabajando en una app que te permite descargar Mods, Complementos y demás cosas para el juego "Minecraft de móviles", quiero que cuando el usuario le de click al botón de descargar y que al descargarse un archivo de formato `.mcaddon` `("Uno de los formatos que Minecraft usa para instalar automáticamente complementos")` se abra ese archivo en Minecraft. Logre abrir el juego al darle al botón pero no se como enviarle el archivo, he visto algunas apps en la play store que lo hacen pero desconozco como. Estuve investigando en Android Developers y otros sitios pero solo encontre como enviar simples datos a otras apps como a la camara, calculadora y maps, pero no fueron de ayuda. [Tambien encontre algo sobre enviar la uri de un file pero me perdí y no entendí](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing?hl=es-419#:%7E:text=Una%20de%20las%20formas%20en,acceso%20temporales%20a%20ese%20URI.), por favor seria de mucha ayuda un ejemplo en Kotlin o Java no importa. Trabajo en la `API 33`

```
binding.btnDownload.setOnClickListener { //Boton de Descarga
            val storageRef = storage.reference //firebase database
            val pathReference = storageRef.child("/AddonsModsMaps/Addons/Complemento_Name.mcaddon")
            val oneMegabyte: Long = 3024 * 3024
            val rootPath = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download")
            if(!rootPath.exists()) {
                rootPath.mkdirs()
            }

            val mcFile = File(rootPath,"Complemento_Name.mcaddon") 
            val cacheFile = File.createTempFile("Complemento_Name", "mcaddon")

            //val fileUri = getUriForFile(baseContext,"StringAuthorization...?",cmFile)
            //  Ni idea de lo que estaba haciendo aqui.


            pathReference.getFile(cacheFile).addOnSuccessListener {//Aqui se descarga el File
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Downloaded" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                 startActivity(Intent(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mojang.minecraftpe")))
                //Aqui se abre el juego, pero como envío el file?

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas lo único que se me ocurre es que el mismo usuario descargue el archivo de ese formato y el mismo sea quien lo meta donde sea. Que lo puedes hacer con la url del archivo donde lo tengas. Entiendo que ese tipo de archivo una vez que el usuario intente acceder a el lo abrirá el mismo minecraft. Entonces lo que yo haría es hacer un Uri con un intent para que se le descargue de forma automática. Esto lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
 var url_uri = Uri.parse(url)//Donde uri sea el enlace de descargar del archivo
                var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url_uri)//para ir a una web donde descargar el archivo

                startActivity(intent)//mandamos al usuario del activity al sitio de descarga. Y el lo que vera es que el sistema quiere descargar un archivo y le dara la opcion de abrirlo con el minecraf. Eso sucede con los pdf y supongo que con los archivos de ese tipo tambien.
```

Comment: Funciona hasta cierto punto pero al parecer en algunos teléfonos móviles no sale la opción de abrir el archivo con Minecraft, así que no parece ser la solución, pero me sirve como segunda opción ya que acabo de encontrar una solución después de investigar por horas, aquí se las dejo por sí otras personas necesitan abrir archivos en otras Apps:

Answer (score 0):

> Solución:

Esto hice en el Manifest.xml

```
</application>
...
<provider
            android: name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
```

Cree un archivo en: res/xml/provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>

    <external-cache-path name="cache" path="."/>
    <!-- No encontre la ruta donde se guarda el chache -->
</paths>
```

En el boton de descargar esto:

```
binding.btnDownload.setOnClickListener { //Boton de Descarga
            val storageRef = storage.reference //firebase database
            val pathReference = storageRef.child("/AddonsModsMaps/Addons/Complemento_Name.mcaddon")
            val oneMegabyte: Long = 3024 * 3024
            val rootPath = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download")
            if(!rootPath.exists()) {
                rootPath.mkdirs()
            }
            val localFile = File(rootPath,"Complemento_Name.mcaddon") 
            val cacheFile = File.createTempFile("Complemento_Name", "mcaddon")

            pathReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {//Aqui se descarga el File
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Downloaded" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

              //Solución aquí 
                val myMime: MimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                val newIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

                val mimeType: String = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(localFile.extension).toString()
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                    newIntent.setDataAndType(
                        getUriForFile(this.applicationContext, this.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", localFile), mimeType)
                } else {
                    newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(localFile), mimeType)
                }
                newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                this.startActivity(newIntent)
            }
        }
```

Encontre la solution en ingles aquí: [stackoverflow.com/questions/61755761](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755761/how-to-open-file-with-another-app-in-android)